# How can I eliminate vim python-mode's 'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs'

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

The complete spurious warning is:

```
equivs3e|1 F| F0002 <class 'AttributeError'>: 'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs' [pylint]
```

I gather it's got something to do with the new AST code in recent 3.x, and happens to some pylint's outside of vim's python-mode, but how can I get rid of that annoying warning inside of vim's python-mode?

It appears that python-mode brings in its own copy of pylint, BTW.

Oh, and I'm using the included vim-gtk3 on Linux Mint 18.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very recent :PluginUpdate in vim fixed the issue for me.  My guess is it was broken in python-mode for a while and they recently fixed it.